# iframe resize issue in firefox

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, iframe, autoresize

i know this is so basic ,its so basic that it hurts me to ask this question but the issue is starting to make my hair too fall out lol.

i'm making a liquid website so everything resizes,so far so good...my page has a couple of iframes ,they will resize just great in i.e using % for height and width but when it comes to firefox only the width will resize and not the height ,the frame ends up pushing over my tables and making the whole thing look wrong

does anyone have a fix/solution to this please.

Comment: Check this:https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_Remote_XUL

Comment: Is the site in standards mode?  Do the iframes have a non-auto-height parent?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979000/iframe-and-conflicting-absolute-positions

Comment: Never, EVER use IE as a reference for how things should work. But without a link or the markup, we can only take wild guesses.

Comment: i'll give a link to the page im working on ..i have found a semi solution using layers (absolute) but it compleatly breaks in ie mainly because the height and width changes
http://www.the-underground.co.uk/ugs/firefoxfinal.html  <<(using layers)

the question is simple really i need iframes to behave the same way as they do in ie when you use frames with the following ,,they shrink and grow where as in firefox they only "squish" horizontaly but not vertically :)
 
<iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="someframe.html"></iframe>

Answer (score 2):

thanks to everyone that tried to help ,it was a bit vauge i managed to solve it in the end simply by

putting the iframe i wanted inside a layer/div set the layer to absolute and size it in % and then add the iframe inside the layer worked a treat for all browsers.