# Javascript to fix iframe height according to available height in the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need Javascript to fix the iframe height dynamically according to available height in the browser ?

Comment: i tried  function resizer() {
            var _iframe = document.getElementById('frmContent');

            var _divIframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
            _iframe.height = window.innerHeight - 135;
            _iframe.width = window.innerWidth - 10;
        }

Comment: but this is working in chrome,IE 9 not in IE 8.

Comment: there this window height is not coming

Comment: you can also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979000/iframe-and-conflicting-absolute-positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$(function(){    
    //sets the height of the iframe to the height of the browser viewport
    $("#idOfIframe").height($(window).height());
}
```