# HTML: Strange space between iframe elements?

Tags: html, xhtml

Question:

Consider the following HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>

<div style="float:left;">
  <div style="background-color: Red; padding-top: 2mm; padding-bottom: 2mm;">
        Dock: Usage controls/symbol list here
    </div>


    <div style="height: 300px; background-color: Khaki; display:block; float:left; overflow: scroll;">

        <ul style="background-color: White; float: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 10px;">
            <li>
                <a href="Folders/Content/Inbox" target="ifrmFolderContent" >
                    Posteingang / Inbox
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Folders/Content/Drafts" target="ifrmFolderContent" >
                    Entwürfe / Drafts
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Folders/Content/Sent Items" target="ifrmFolderContent" >
                    Gesendet / Sent Items
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                Archiv / Archive
            </li>
            <li>
                Papierkorb / Trash
            </li>
            <li>
                Junk / Crap
            </li>
            <li>
                Scam
            </li>
            <li>
                Spam
            </li>
            <li>
                Virus
            </li>
            <li>
                Abrufen / Send & Receive
            </li>
            <li>
                Verfassen / Compose
            </li>
            <li>
                Adressbuch / Address book
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>




    <div style="width: 400px; height: 300px; background-color: Green; display:block; float:left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">



       <iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0"  name="ifrmFolderContent" src="http://www.yahoo.com" frameborder="0" style="overflow: none; width: 400px; height: 150px; background-color: Orange; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">

         Folder Content
       </iframe>



       <iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0"  name="ifrmEmail" src="http://www.msn.com" frameborder="0" style="overflow: none; width: 400px; height: 150px; background-color: Orange; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">

         E-Mail Content

       </iframe>



    </div>



    <div style="background-color: Indigo; padding-top: 2mm; padding-bottom: 2mm; clear: left;">
        Copyright here
    </div>

</div>



</body>

</html>
```

It renders exactly as one would expect (Chrome + IE8).

But now, I add:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

on top of it.

And suddenly, I get 2 to 5 mm of green space between the two `iframe`s (folder content / email content), in both Chrome and IE8 (haven't tested FireFox).
What is even more disturbing, there seems to be no way to get rid of this space (except from removing `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Why? I mean, the green comes from the `background-color` of the parent element, but why is there some space between the two `iframe`s ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Just add

```
<style>iframe { vertical-align:bottom; } </style>
```

or

```
<style>iframe { display:block; } </style>
```

`<!DOCTYPE html>` puts the browser into standards mode, where inline elements are placed on the baseline of the containing block and a space for the character descenders is always allocated in the line box. In other modes, that space is only created when there are printable characters on the same line as the iframes which isn't the case here. Moving the iframe off the baseline by either of the methods above allows the space for the descenders to be placed within the height of the iframe.

Comment: Now answer me a much harder question: _Why_ is iframe `display:inline` by default?

Comment: @PaulSkinner See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953472/why-are-iframes-inline-elements-by-default

Answer (score 17):

An `iframe` in standards mode is `display: inline` by default.  That means they will be placed on the text baseline, ie. where the bottom of an 'a' ends, not where the bottom of a 'y' does.  The gap you're seeing is the space for descenders in the line of text.  This should remove it:

```
iframe { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick note (Because I was having this problem on IE)...

Trying setting:

```
font-size: 0px;
```

This worked (I believe because, as someone suggested, the iframes are places on the text baseline).

Goodluck y'all!

Comment: This should get upvoted more. You need this to make vertical-align: bottom to work in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the `seamless` attribute, which is introduced in HTML 5. http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_iframe_tag.cfm

Comment: Having the same issue, the ``seamless`` attribute doesn't seem to change a thing for me. Just to let others know, never know.

Comment: The `seamless` attribute no longer exists
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804604/html5-iframe-seamless-attribute