# Why are iframes inline-elements by default?

Tags: css, html, iframe, layout

### iframe = Inline?

While debugging some layout problem today I was surprised to see that `<iframe>` elements have a default display property of `inline`.

For me this seems strange, especially considering that you can apply a `height` and `width` to an `<iframe>` that is respected by the browser, which should not be the case for a simple inline-element.

So can anyone explain me the reasoning behind this?

### Demo

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="test"></iframe>
```

**CSS**

```
alert($('#test').css('display'))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0tdLr9pq/

Thanks!

Comment: `iframe`s have to have a closing tag, btw.

Comment: Edited to add closing tag, doesn't change the result of course.

Comment: That’s why I said “btw” at the end.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because the HTML4 spec said so:

> The [`IFRAME`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html#edef-IFRAME) element allows authors to insert a frame within a
>   block of text. Inserting an inline frame within a section of text is
>   much like inserting an object via the [`OBJECT`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#edef-OBJECT) element: they both
>   allow you to insert an HTML document in the middle of another, they
>   may both be aligned with surrounding text, etc.

The "*be aligned with surrounding text*" part means they shouldn't be block-level by default.

And it's true that, usually, inline elements ignore the `height` and `width` properties:

> [**10.3.1 Inline, non-replaced elements**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-width)
>
> The [`width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width) property does not apply.
>
> [**10.6.1 Inline, non-replaced elements**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced)
>
> The [`height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height) property does not apply.

But that's not true for replaced elements, like `iframe`. This is explained in [10.3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width) and [10.6.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height) sections.

Comment: How does that differ from inline-block elements like 'img'?

Comment: @aKzenT It's the same. Images are also inline by default, not inline-block.

Comment: But isn't that strange? It's seems like inline-block would be the logical choice as it seems to behave the same as inline replaced elements. Is there a historic component like replaced elements existing before "inline-block"?

Comment: @aKzenT Probably, that's because `inline-block` was introduced by CSS 2.1 (2011), but CSS 2 (1998) didn't have it. Therefore, HTML 4.01 (1999) couldn't recommend `inline-block` as the default style for replaced elements.

Answer (score 1):

IFRAME stand for Inline Frame. See this : http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html#h-16.5

Comment: This is not an explanation. It called an "inline-frame" to differentiate it from normal frames in HTML4 framesets. In fact in the HTML5 spec it does no longer say "inline frame". http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element

Comment: @aKzenT : Sorry my knowledge is limited, feel free to edit my answer or create your own.