# Is there a way to programmatically determine if a user is getting Flash or native video from YouTube

Tags: html, video, youtube

I am trying to answer [my own question about seamless and sandbox for YouTube videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324159/is-there-any-point-in-using-the-seamless-and-or-sandbox-attribute-for-youtube-if) more in depth. Work has begun at a [test page](http://keryx.se/dev/html5/sandboxed-seamless-youtube-test.html)

Note that form elements do not work at all so far.

I would like to automatically determine if the user **gets** Flash or native video from YouTube. (**Not** what the user **can** get.) Under normal circumstances I'd suppose this is "none of my business" and it is perhaps impossible, because of security restrictions.

Is it possible? If so, how?