# What is the difference between srcdoc="..." and src="data:text/html,..." in an <iframe>?

Tags: html, iframe

For example, which is the difference between these:

```
<iframe srcdoc="<p>Some HTML</p>"></iframe>
<iframe src="data:text/html,<p>Some HTML</p>"></iframe>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Wf8L/)

And, in case they are exactly the same, why did HTML5 add `srcdoc` attribute?

**Edit**

Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I am not comparing `src` with `srcdoc`, but `src` using text/html data URI with `srcdoc`.

Then, if the functionality chart is like this

```
                   |  src attribute       |  srcdoc attribute
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
  URL              |  Yes                 |  No without using src (*)
  HTML content     |  Yes, using data URI |  Yes
```

why is `srcdoc` needed?

---

**(*) Note**:

It seems `srcdoc` can be used to load a page by URL ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Wf8L/3/)), using a subiframe with `src`attribute:

```
<iframe srcdoc="<iframe src='http://microsoft.com'></iframe>"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 70):

The other answers list some superficial differences, but really miss the mark of the key difference that explains *why* browsers/spec writers would essentially duplicate something that already exists:

`<iframe src="data:...untrusted content" sandbox />` <- Secure in modern browsers, **insecure** in legacy browsers with no sandbox support

`<iframe srcdoc="...untrusted content"   sandbox />` <- Secure in modern browsers, **secure** (though non-functional) in legacy browsers

This new syntax provides content authors a way to protect their users, even when they may be using legacy browsers. Without it, content authors would be reluctant to use the sandbox feature at all, and it would not see use.

Comment: If the main benefit is untrusted content, why spec it to contain the content inline — doesn't most untrusted content come from external URLs?  I.e. why not `sandboxedsrc` attribute that takes a [data] URI?  (It'd also avoid some future browser from implementing srcdoc without implementing sandbox).

Comment: Because authors can already use external urls (on a separate domain) to serve untrusted content.

Comment: What do you mean by secure? It can’t access the embedding page? The embedding paye can’t access it? Or both? Or what

Comment: Otherwise What is the point of this over a regular div or HTML component

Comment: Any article on iframe's "sandbox" will discuss what benefits it provides

Answer (score 23):

From [MDN documentation on the `srcdoc` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#srcdoc) :

> **Inline HTML** to embed, **overriding the `src` attribute**. If a browser does not support the `srcdoc` attribute, it will **fall back to the URL in the `src` attribute.**

[Older MDN documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20131003004733/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) on `srcdoc` says:

> The **content** of the page that the embedded context is to contain. This attribute is expected to be used together with the `sandbox` and `seamless` attributes.

**So, the `srcdoc` attribute overrides the content embedded using `src` attribute.**

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JWeeh/)

(Note: The [`seamless` attribute has since been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5632609/1175496), and [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30507852/1175496) describes how `sandbox` attribute **should be "used with the `srcdoc` attribute"**; both attributes were introduced in HTML5; `sandbox` should be used in case the `srcdoc` **contains untrusted content**.

---

Also, what you are saying about the following snippet `data:text/html` is called [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs) and **it might have length limitations, so `src` is limited in what it can show, whereas `srcdoc` is less limited.**

MSDN mentions [length limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> Data URIs cannot be larger than 32,768 characters.

But other browsers might have [different data URL length limits (higher limits) on data URLs themselves](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs#length_limitations) (see Chromium might allow 512 URLs), but [still not allow URLs to exceed 2MB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41755526/1175496)

Comment: "So, the `srcdoc` attribute overrides the content embedded using `src` attribute." Apparently not in Firefox 24, I see two IFrames with Microsoft's website in it.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel The first version of Firefox which supports `srcdoc` is 25 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @MrAlien Good point about the length limitation of data URIs, unlike html attributes which [have no limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496096/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-html-attributes). Anyway, it seems that limit is imposed by Microsoft implementation, because [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs) don't say anything about a limit, and the [RFC standard](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2397) only says "*Note that some applications that use URLs may impose a length limit*"

Comment: @MarcelKorpel take aalook at seamless attribute and other newer html5 attributes and you will get why you need srcdoc

Comment: @Oriol thank you and yes, mdn doesn't specify any limits but aamsure uri do have limits

Comment: @Mr.Alien Regarding your last comment: Can you put the why in your answer? I'm updating my knowledge of html5 now and have read the html5 attributes associated with <iframe>; But the necessity of srcdoc hasn't become clear to me. PS: I came across this answer during my research, so any indication of how the other html5 attributes merit the existence of srcdoc, is welcome.

Comment: The reason why `srcdoc` is necessary (as implied, but not explicitly stated, in this answer) is that [data URIs are not universally supported for HTML content](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri).  This means that a browser which does not support a data URI in `src` has no graceful fallback method to display the content.  However, using `srcdoc` with an http URI in `src` which resolves to the same embedded content _does_ provide browsers with a graceful degradation option.

Comment: Is that data URI limit real? HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL regularly returns dataURLs larger than 32k

Answer (score 23):

iframe with `src` attribute with HTML Content **is cross domain**. This is true even with [data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs) as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

> `data:` URLs get a **new**, empty, security context.

But iframe with `srcdoc` attribute with HTML Content is **not cross domain**.

So using the `src` attribute might **cause errors** if you try to access/manipulate the iframe from the parent page:

> Blocked a frame with origin "..." from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: That's a good point, Chrome treats data URIs as cross domain. Firefox treats them as same origin, not sure what Edge does.

Comment: What do you mean by “not cross domain”?

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak "Not cross-domain", meaning the iframe content will be treated as coming from same domain as the parent-page. Thus, it won't be restricted by browser same-origin policy, which normally prevents browser from accessing content of the remote page, as it would be when you use src='some-url.com'. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 15):

As of writing - srcdoc in Chrome  (v36) allows the setting and fetching of cookies, whereas the use of src with data URL does not:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:' URLs

This may or may not be important to you, but rules out the use of data URLs in the application I am building, which is a shame, as of course IE doesn't support srcdoc currently (v11).

Comment: Good point. Data URIs have limitations on some browsers, so `srcdoc` works better in those cases.

Comment: In Chromium 81 parent frame background and font styles also cascade into the iframe, adding even more utility.

Answer (score 9):

Another noticeable difference is that `src` attributes with data-uri support URI percent-encoding rules while `srcdoc` doesn't as it supports regular html syntax,

these sources will yield differently:

```html
<iframe srcdoc="<p>hello%20world</p><h1>give%0D%0Ame%0D%0Asome%24</h1>"></iframe>

<iframe src="data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,<p>hello%20datauri<p><h1>give%0D%0A me%0D%0Asome%24</h1>"></iframe>
```

I also noticed a difference in the parsing of js scripts inside the attributes value( it's probably more than just percentage-encoding ) but didn't figure the rule yet...

Comment: The content of `src` has to be URL-encoded to be treated correctly. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238890/convert-html-to-datatext-html-link-using-javascript) for details on how to do that.

Comment: I didn't have much luck URI encoding attribute values on larger textfiles. What worked for me was to sanitize input using recode(1) in bash beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Another difference is how links to fragments inside the iframe HTML work.  Let's say your HTML content has a link/`<a>` pointing to a [document fragment/hash/id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Text_fragments) somewhere **in the same page**, like this:

```
<a href="#in_src"></a>

<!-- lots of other content, requiring scrolling -->

<p id="in_src"></p>
```

- If you use the `src` attribute, ([example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmc824zt/4/), or [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/tufafayivi/edit?html,js,output)) the same link will **scroll/jump you to the relevant fragment** (as I expected).
- If you use the `srcdoc` attribute, ([example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmc824zt/7/), or [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/fizeyexasu/4/edit?html,js,output)) a fragment link like the above will try to **re-navigate the entire `iframe` to a whole new page**, (based on the parent page's context? I'm not sure, but it's not what I expected)

Maybe this is because of [the difference in domains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41800811/1175496) in `srcdoc` vs `src`? Maybe the difference in their [`baseURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURI) values (see more below?). I'm not sure

I tested this on Chrome Version 111.0.5563.149 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**EDIT**

I wanted to the link to scroll/jump to the document fragment, even with a `srcdoc` attribute. So
in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/w2xpz7jq/4/) I used Javascript to...

- `addEventListener()` for the click event
- `event.preventDefault()` (to prevent the anchor's iframe-resetting behavior)
- and [use `location.hash= '#in_src';`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3163635/1175496) to manually jump to the doc fragment.

Note that the values of `e.target.attributes.href.value` and `e.target.href` do not necessarily have the same value (i.e. the value of the fragment ''#in_src'`)

- The `attributes.href.value` **is the literal string value** of the href attribute, like `'#in_src'`
- But [the `href` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/href) of the `HTMLAnchorElement` API has a  "a string [value] containing **the whole URL**"

  - in the case of `srcdoc`, the `href` value is something like `'https://...#i01'` (the [`baseURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURI) value is the **parent's URL** (`iframeWindow.parent.document.baseURI`), and maybe that's why clicking the link will *navigate the whole iframe*)
  - in the case of `src` using a data URI, the `href` value is something like  `'data:text/html,...#i01`, (the [`baseURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURI) value is **the data URI**, and will jump to the fragment instead of navigating the hwole page)

Answer (score -1):

In your example the two forms are functionally identical. However, you can use both `src` and `srcdoc` attributes, allowing non-HTML5 browsers to use the `src` version, while HTML5 browsers can use the `srcdoc` version along with the `sandbox` and `seamless` attributes which offer more flexibility in how an iFrame is treated.

Comment: But `sandbox` and `seamless` attributes can be used too with `src` attribute, can't they? It seems to me that it's `src` which is more flexible than `srcdoc`

Comment: @Oriol, I think my answer goes directly to why this is important, not as a flaw, but as a feature

Answer (score -4):

The main difference is that the 'src' attribute contains the address of the document you are going to embed in the  tag.

On the other hand 'srcdoc'attribute contains the HTML content of the page to show in the inline frame.

*the main disadvantage of srcdoc is that it is not supported in all browsers whereas src is compatible with all the browsers.*

for detailed explanation please go through the following link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: But `src` attribute can contain the HTML content of the page too, using data URIs

Answer (score -4):

**srcdoc:** The content of the page that the embedded context is to contain. This attribute is expected to be used together with the sandbox and seamless attributes. If a browser supports the srcdoc attribute, it will override the content specified in the src attribute (if present). If a browser does NOT support the srcdoc attribute, it will show the file specified in the src attribute instead (if present).

**src:** The URL of the page to embed.

Comment: But `src` attribute can contain the HTML content of the page too, using data URIs