# Why cant I access iframe's document with src or srcdoc attributes set?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <!-- <iframe id="iff" srcdoc="<div>ok</div>"></iframe> -->
    <iframe id="iff" src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3Cdiv%3Eok%3C%2Fdiv%3E"></iframe>
    <script>
        console.log(document.getElementById('iff').contentWindow.document)
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

1. I set `srcdoc` (tried `src` also) of `<iframe>`, but cannot access the real document of the `iframe` (tried `iframeElement.contentDocument` also). Chrome outputs (also tried Firefox):
   [image: result]

I see in [Get IFrame's document, from JavaScript in main document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999101/get-iframes-document-from-javascript-in-main-document) that I cannot get the document of a cross-domain iframe, and also learned from [Which is the difference between srcdoc="..." and src="data:text/html,..." in an <iframe>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739001/which-is-the-difference-between-srcdoc-and-src-datatext-html-in-an) that `src` and `srcdoc` behaves different about cross-domain behavior. But I tried both, none works.

**2. When I append a child to the document body of an iframe (*with `src` attribute set*), the DOM updates but it doesnt show on screen.**

Comment: What is in console is not what it actually is with DOM concerning iframes.

Comment: @zer00ne but I cant manipulate the iframe's DOM (with src set) either, such as appendChild

Comment: If you have an iframe with srcdoc and you want to get content from it to the parent page use `importNode()` to copy or `adoptNode()` to move.

Comment: @zer00ne Well that could work so thanks! But I still wonder if there is an explanation for this behavior in W3C documents?

Comment: The conflicts you are experiencing is due to a slew of security measures, the very environment that you are testing in determines different behavior from the next. **Do not believe what the Developer Tools show you when it involves accessing the iframe it will LIE**

Comment: Now that makes sense. Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
window.frames['iff'].document.myvar;
```

This can be useful if you look for the iframe with the url:

```
var x=getIframeID("cool.php");
x.contentWindow.callafunction();

function getIframeID(iframeurl) {
    var iFs = top.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    var x, i = iFs.length;
    while ( i-- ){
        x = iFs[i];
        if(iframeurl.indexOf(x.src)>=0) return (x.id);
        if (x.src == iframeurl)         return (x.id);
    }
    return("");
}
```