# iFrame Attributes with Featherlight.js plugin

Tags: featherlight.js

How do I use the plugin to set scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" width="900px" height="570px" and other iframe attributes using the featherlight.js plugin? I can't for the life of me figure it out. I am a like a newborn child with jquery. My apologies.

```js
/**
 * Featherlight - ultra slim jQuery lightbox
 * Version 1.3.1 - http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/
 *
 * Copyright 2015, Noël Raoul Bossart (http://www.noelboss.com)
 * MIT Licensed.
**/
!function(a){"use strict";function b(a,c){if(!(this instanceof b)){var d=new b(a,c);return d.open(),d}this.id=b.id++,this.setup(a,c),this.chainCallbacks(b._callbackChain)}if("undefined"==typeof a)return void("console"in window&&window.console.info("Too much lightness, Featherlight needs jQuery."));var c=[],d=function(b){return c=a.grep(c,function(a){return a!==b&&a.$instance.closest("body").length>0})},e=function(a,b){var c={},d=new RegExp("^"+b+"([A-Z])(.*)");for(var e in a){var f=e.match(d);if(f){var g=(f[1]+f[2].replace(/([A-Z])/g,"-$1")).toLowerCase();c[g]=a[e]}}return c},f={keyup:"onKeyUp",resize:"onResize"},g=function(c){a.each(b.opened().reverse(),function(){return c.isDefaultPrevented()||!1!==this[f[c.type]](c)?void 0:(c.preventDefault(),c.stopPropagation(),!1)})},h=function(c){if(c!==b._globalHandlerInstalled){b._globalHandlerInstalled=c;var d=a.map(f,function(a,c){return c+"."+b.prototype.namespace}).join(" ");a(window)[c?"on":"off"](d,g)}};b.prototype={constructor:b,namespace:"featherlight",targetAttr:"data-featherlight",variant:null,resetCss:!1,background:null,openTrigger:"click",closeTrigger:"click",filter:null,root:"body",openSpeed:250,closeSpeed:250,closeOnClick:"background",closeOnEsc:!0,closeIcon:"&#10005;",loading:"",persist:!1,otherClose:null,beforeOpen:a.noop,beforeContent:a.noop,beforeClose:a.noop,afterOpen:a.noop,afterContent:a.noop,afterClose:a.noop,onKeyUp:a.noop,onResize:a.noop,type:null,contentFilters:["jquery","image","html","ajax","iframe","text"],setup:function(b,c){"object"!=typeof b||b instanceof a!=!1||c||(c=b,b=void 0);var d=a.extend(this,c,{target:b}),e=d.resetCss?d.namespace+"-reset":d.namespace,f=a(d.background||['<div class="'+e+"-loading "+e+'">','<div class="'+e+'-content">','<span class="'+e+"-close-icon "+d.namespace+'-close">',d.closeIcon,"</span>",'<div class="'+d.namespace+'-inner">'+d.loading+"</div>","</div>","</div>"].join("")),g="."+d.namespace+"-close"+(d.otherClose?","+d.otherClose:"");return d.$instance=f.clone().addClass(d.variant),d.$instance.on(d.closeTrigger+"."+d.namespace,function(b){var c=a(b.target);("background"===d.closeOnClick&&c.is("."+d.namespace)||"anywhere"===d.closeOnClick||c.closest(g).length)&&(b.preventDefault(),d.close())}),this},getContent:function(){if(this.persist!==!1&&this.$content)return this.$content;var b=this,c=this.constructor.contentFilters,d=function(a){return b.$currentTarget&&b.$currentTarget.attr(a)},e=d(b.targetAttr),f=b.target||e||"",g=c[b.type];if(!g&&f in c&&(g=c[f],f=b.target&&e),f=f||d("href")||"",!g)for(var h in c)b[h]&&(g=c[h],f=b[h]);if(!g){var i=f;if(f=null,a.each(b.contentFilters,function(){return g=c[this],g.test&&(f=g.test(i)),!f&&g.regex&&i.match&&i.match(g.regex)&&(f=i),!f}),!f)return"console"in window&&window.console.error("Featherlight: no content filter found "+(i?' for "'+i+'"':" (no target specified)")),!1}return g.process.call(b,f)},setContent:function(b){var c=this;return(b.is("iframe")||a("iframe",b).length>0)&&c.$instance.addClass(c.namespace+"-iframe"),c.$instance.removeClass(c.namespace+"-loading"),c.$instance.find("."+c.namespace+"-inner").not(b).slice(1).remove().end().replaceWith(a.contains(c.$instance[0],b[0])?"":b),c.$content=b.addClass(c.namespace+"-inner"),c},open:function(b){var d=this;if(d.$instance.hide().appendTo(d.root),!(b&&b.isDefaultPrevented()||d.beforeOpen(b)===!1)){b&&b.preventDefault();var e=d.getContent();if(e)return c.push(d),h(!0),d.$instance.fadeIn(d.openSpeed),d.beforeContent(b),a.when(e).always(function(a){d.setContent(a),d.afterContent(b)}).then(d.$instance.promise()).done(function(){d.afterOpen(b)})}return d.$instance.detach(),a.Deferred().reject().promise()},close:function(b){var c=this,e=a.Deferred();return c.beforeClose(b)===!1?e.reject():(0===d(c).length&&h(!1),c.$instance.fadeOut(c.closeSpeed,function(){c.$instance.detach(),c.afterClose(b),e.resolve()})),e.promise()},chainCallbacks:function(b){for(var c in b)this[c]=a.proxy(b[c],this,a.proxy(this[c],this))}},a.extend(b,{id:0,autoBind:"[data-featherlight]",defaults:b.prototype,contentFilters:{jquery:{regex:/^[#.]\w/,test:function(b){return b instanceof a&&b},process:function(b){return this.persist!==!1?a(b):a(b).clone(!0)}},image:{regex:/\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|tiff|bmp)(\?\S*)?$/i,process:function(b){var c=this,d=a.Deferred(),e=new Image,f=a('<img src="'+b+'" alt="" class="'+c.namespace+'-image" />');return e.onload=function(){f.naturalWidth=e.width,f.naturalHeight=e.height,d.resolve(f)},e.onerror=function(){d.reject(f)},e.src=b,d.promise()}},html:{regex:/^\s*<[\w!][^<]*>/,process:function(b){return a(b)}},ajax:{regex:/./,process:function(b){var c=a.Deferred(),d=a("<div></div>").load(b,function(a,b){"error"!==b&&c.resolve(d.contents()),c.fail()});return c.promise()}},iframe:{process:function(b){var c=new a.Deferred,d=a("<iframe/>").hide().attr("src",b).css(e(this,"iframe")).on("load",function(){c.resolve(d.show())}).appendTo(this.$instance.find("."+this.namespace+"-content"));return c.promise()}},text:{process:function(b){return a("<div>",{text:b})}}},functionAttributes:["beforeOpen","afterOpen","beforeContent","afterContent","beforeClose","afterClose"],readElementConfig:function(b,c){var d=this,e=new RegExp("^data-"+c+"-(.*)"),f={};return b&&b.attributes&&a.each(b.attributes,function(){var b=this.name.match(e);if(b){var c=this.value,g=a.camelCase(b[1]);if(a.inArray(g,d.functionAttributes)>=0)c=new Function(c);else try{c=a.parseJSON(c)}catch(h){}f[g]=c}}),f},extend:function(b,c){var d=function(){this.constructor=b};return d.prototype=this.prototype,b.prototype=new d,b.__super__=this.prototype,a.extend(b,this,c),b.defaults=b.prototype,b},attach:function(b,c,d){var e=this;"object"!=typeof c||c instanceof a!=!1||d||(d=c,c=void 0),d=a.extend({},d);var f,g=d.namespace||e.defaults.namespace,h=a.extend({},e.defaults,e.readElementConfig(b[0],g),d);return b.on(h.openTrigger+"."+h.namespace,h.filter,function(g){var i=a.extend({$source:b,$currentTarget:a(this)},e.readElementConfig(b[0],h.namespace),e.readElementConfig(this,h.namespace),d),j=f||a(this).data("featherlight-persisted")||new e(c,i);"shared"===j.persist?f=j:j.persist!==!1&&a(this).data("featherlight-persisted",j),j.open(g)}),b},current:function(){var a=this.opened();return a[a.length-1]||null},opened:function(){var b=this;return d(),a.grep(c,function(a){return a instanceof b})},close:function(){var a=this.current();return a?a.close():void 0},_onReady:function(){var b=this;b.autoBind&&(b.attach(a(document),{filter:b.autoBind}),a(b.autoBind).filter("[data-featherlight-filter]").each(function(){b.attach(a(this))}))},_callbackChain:{onKeyUp:function(a,b){return 27===b.keyCode?(this.closeOnEsc&&this.$instance.find("."+this.namespace+"-close:first").click(),!1):a(b)},onResize:function(a,b){if(this.$content.naturalWidth){var c=this.$content.naturalWidth,d=this.$content.naturalHeight;this.$content.css("width","").css("height","");var e=Math.max(c/parseInt(this.$content.parent().css("width"),10),d/parseInt(this.$content.parent().css("height"),10));e>1&&this.$content.css("width",""+c/e+"px").css("height",""+d/e+"px")}return a(b)},afterContent:function(a,b){var c=a(b);return this.onResize(b),c}}}),a.featherlight=b,a.fn.featherlight=function(a,c){return b.attach(this,a,c)},a(document).ready(function(){b._onReady()})}(jQuery);
```

```css
/**
 * Featherlight - ultra slim jQuery lightbox
 * Version 1.3.1 - http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/
 *
 * Copyright 2015, NoÃ«l Raoul Bossart (http://www.noelboss.com)
 * MIT Licensed.
**/
@media all{.featherlight{display:none;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;z-index:2147483647;text-align:center;white-space:nowrap;cursor:pointer;background:#333;background:rgba(0,0,0,0)}.featherlight:last-of-type{background:rgba(0,0,0,.8)}.featherlight:before{content:'';display:inline-block;height:100%;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:-.25em}.featherlight .featherlight-content{position:relative;text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block;overflow:auto;padding:25px 25px 0;border-bottom:25px solid transparent;min-width:30%;margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%;max-height:95%;background:#fff;cursor:auto;white-space:normal}.featherlight .featherlight-inner{display:block}.featherlight .featherlight-close-icon{position:absolute;z-index:9999;top:0;right:0;line-height:25px;width:25px;cursor:pointer;text-align:center;font:Arial,sans-serif;background:#fff;background:rgba(255,255,255,.3);color:#000}.featherlight .featherlight-image{width:100%}.featherlight-iframe .featherlight-content{border-bottom:0;padding:0}.featherlight iframe{border:0}}@media only screen and (max-width:1024px){.featherlight .featherlight-content{margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;max-height:98%;padding:10px 10px 0;border-bottom:10px solid transparent}}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.example.com/" width="900px" data-featherlight="iframe">Release the iFrame</a>
```

[FeatherLight Plugin](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#open-lightbox-with-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

For those that have CSS equivalent (`width` and `height` are even in the example doc), you can specify those as data attributes or options.

For example: `scrolling: no` is `overflow:hidden` in css, so this would work:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" data-featherlight-iframe-overflow="hidden" ...>
```

Looks like `seamless` is [not yet supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804604/html5-iframe-seamless-attribute) so you might want to use CSS too.

For actual attributes, you'll have to use the `afterContent` callback to add them with javascript, as there is no support for that otherwise.