# Should I still use seamless attribute for iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

Should I still use "seamless" attribute inside `<iframe>` tag in html or is it dead in html5 (at least I saw one page that told this). So should I still learn it or its not worthy? Thanks for answers.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804604/html5-iframe-seamless-attribute

Answer (score 2):

According to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-seamless), there are no current browsers that support the `seamless` attribute for `iframes`.

> The seamless attribute makes an iframe's contents actually part of a
>   page, and adopts the styles from its hosting page. The attribute has
>   been removed from both the [WHATWG](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/331) and the [W3C HTML5](https://github.com/w3c/html/pull/325) specifications.