# How to make iframe's height 100% ..?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like the google map iframe to occupy 100% of the height, as of now it is only around 150px. The coding is as shown below, what should I do, please help me.

```
<iframe width="67%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp; 
    source=s_q&amp;
    hl=en&amp;
    geocode=&amp;
    q=Prabhakar.C,+ICON+Design+Studio,+sathy+road,+Ganapathy,+87-A,+First+floor,+muniappakoil+thottam,,+Coimbatore,+Tamil+Nadu&amp;aq=1&amp;sll=21.125498,81.914063&amp;sspn=55.331887,107.138672&amp;
    ie=UTF8&amp;
    hq=Prabhakar.C,+ICON+Design+Studio,+sathy+road,+Ganapathy,+87-A,+First+floor,+muniappakoil+thottam,,&amp;hnear=Coimbatore,+Tamil+Nadu&amp;t=m&amp;
    ll=11.041457,76.983948&amp;
    spn=0.080872,0.109863&amp;
    z=13&amp;iwloc=A&amp;
    output=embed">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 10):

100% height can only be achieved if the parent div's height is set. If the parent div has, for example, a height of 500px, a child div with a height of 100% would have a height of 500px.

Since the iframe's parent is `body` (as long as it is the only element on the page) then you have to set the height of `body` to 100%:

```
body {
    height:100%;
}
```

But body has a parent element too—`html`. So you have to set `html`'s height as well:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
```

Then your iframe:

```
<iframe height="100%" src="..."></iframe>
```

Should stretch to the window's height.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this css.

```
html, body, div, iframe { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }
iframe { position:fixed; display:block; width:100%; border:none; }
```

If nothing happens you can try using javascript:

```
iframe = document.getElementById("frameId");
frame_height = 500;

iframe.height = frame_height;
```

if nothing happens, check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325273/make-iframe-to-fit-100-of-containers-remaining-height)

Answer (score -3):

remove the "150px" from you code and replace it with "100%"