# including one html file into another

Tags: html

i want to include one html file into another, but it doesnt seem to work out
the two files are
C:/wamp/www/AuctionVilla/index.html
and
C:/wamp/www/AuctionVilla/header.html

here's my index.html file

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="CSS/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="index_container">
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td>
    <table width="1000px" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
       <tr>
       <td colspan="3">
          <!--#include virtual="C:/wamp/www/AuctionVilla/header.html" -->
       </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td colspan="3">&nbsp
       </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td width="350px">
       </td>
       <td width="5px" rowspan="3">&nbsp
       </td>
       <td width="650px" rowspan="3">
          <div id="product_container" class="divcontainer" style="width: 645px; height: 500px;">
          </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="350px" height="5px">
        </td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
        <td width="350px" height="355px">
           <div id="movie_container" class="divcontainer" style="width: 350px; height: 355px;">
          </div>
        </td>
        </tr>     
    </table>      
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's my header.html file

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>header</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="CSS/headerMenu.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="main_body">
    <div>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr>
      <td>
         <object classid="clsid:1" codebase="../UAuction/Images/matrimony.swf" width="1000" height="228">
         <param name="Images/matrimony.swf" />
         <param name="quality" value="high" />
         <embed src="../UAuction/Images/matrimony.swf" quality="high" 
         pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="1000" height="228" wmode="transparent">
         </embed>
         </object>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="topmenu">
    <table align="center" bgcolor="#000000">
     <tr> 
     <td>
   <ul id="css3menu">
        <li><a href="../UAuction/index.php">&nbsp Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&nbsp Category</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Art</a>
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Paintings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sculptures</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </li>    
            <li><a href="#">Books</a>
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Book</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Documentaries</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </li>    
            <li><a href="#">Furniture</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Chair</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Wardrobe</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Table</a></li>                       
                </ul>
            </li>   
            <li><a href="#">Sport Goods</a>
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Cricket</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Football</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Rugby</a></li>                       
                </ul>
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="../UAuction/register.php">&nbsp Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">&nbsp Top Bidders</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">&nbsp Top Sellers</a></li>
    <li><a href="../UAuction/contact_us.php">&nbsp Contact Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Offices</a></li>                       
        </ul>
    </li>    
    <li><a href="../UAuction/about_us.php">About Us &nbsp</a></li>     
</ul> 
     </td>
     </tr>
    </table>                 
    </div>
</div>
<script src="../UAuction/JQUERY/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>   
<script src="../UAuction/JQUERY/jquery.effects.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../UAuction/JQUERY/script.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

i dnt knw whta seems to wrong, but it isnt workking fr me...

i tried to change the html to shtml but the file doesnt include at all..

Comment: How specifically are you including one file in another? How is the latter file a header file? It looks like a complete html document.

Comment: Your include looks like ASP syntax. Nevertheless, it's not standard html in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have HTML on your server, or you need only HTML files, you can use frames.

```
<frameset rows="25%,75%">
  <frame src="header.html" />
  <frame src="index.html" />
</frameset>
```

or `iframes` like this (in your `index.html` file):

```
<iframe src="header.html" />
```

But, it is not recommended as it creates a kind of table. If you have PHP on your server, create a PHP file, and use

```
include("header.html");
```

If you have SSI (Server Side Includes) on your webserver, then have this:

```
<!--#include virtual="header.html" -->
```

Personally, I suggest you to use PHP method.

Comment: he could also use an `iframe`.

Comment: but u knw, i want to create a html file, bcause we are told to create it on html, not on php...i knw php method, but i was just asked to create it as a html file...if i use php method then it will have an php extension..

Comment: @SpliFF: Thanks! Haven't used iframes for a long time now. ^_^

Comment: @Saswat: Edited the reply. iframe is a good option too.

Comment: but doesnt i frame gives a scrollbar along with it???

Comment: Check this page @Saswat http://stackoverflow.com/a/325334/1190388

Answer (score 1):

The only "include" mechanisms in HTML itself are (i)frames and objects.

HTML doesn't have an 'include' mechanism - I'm not sure where you've seen these solutions on StackOverflow. You've probably been looking at answers for a server side language such as PHP or ASP.