# iframe reaches bottom of page

Tags: html, iframe, styles, height

Is there a way to make the height of the `<iframe>` reach exactly the bottom of the page? It is hard to judge by using `height:xx%`, and it might be dependent on browser.

The code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="margin:0">
<p style="margin:10px"> hello </p>
<iframe src="http://www.weather.com" style="width:100%; height:95%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `style="position:absolute;"`

Comment: And what should the height be set to?

Comment: It doesn't work.. it just sets the height to the height of the whole screen. But since there's the paragraph `<p ..> .. </p>`, the bottom of the iframe falls off the screen.

Comment: Can you add any HTML? And/or, are those your entire page contents?

Comment: @A.M.K The code in the question is my entire page content.

Comment: Can you change the HTML? Or only CSS?

Comment: @A.M.K You can change anything as long as the output is as desired.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using JavaScript/jQuery, you can precisely set the right dimension for the `IFRAME` element, without the need to access to DOM of the frame itself (cross-domain issues), relying on tables or absolute positioning (useless if the content above the frame is dynamic in height):

```
$(function() {
    var aboveHeight = $("#aboveFrame").outerHeight(true);
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('#frame').height( $(window).height() - aboveHeight );
    }).resize();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hongaar/jsdYz/

Comment: I tried it locally and it looks [pretty much perfect](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLuRE/).

Comment: But but it has no magic! I thought it is html\css magic special olympics then you came with js-hammer and took the prize :)

Answer (score 1):

As annoying as it is to use tables for layout, they're still the best way to consistently handle vertical dimensions.  The following still displays a few white pixels around the edge of the iframe, and has an extra scrollbar in some versions of Firefox, but is as close as I've been able to achieve:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="padding:0; margin:0; height:100%">
  <body style="padding:0; margin:0; height:100%">
    <table style="border:0; padding:0; margin:0; height:100%; width:100%">
      <tr style="border:0; padding:0; margin:0">
        <td style="border:0; padding:0; margin:0">
          <p style="margin:10px"> hello </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="border:0; padding:0; margin:0">
        <td style="border:0; padding:0; margin:0; height:100%">
          <iframe src="http://www.weather.com" style="border:0; padding:0; margin:0; width:100%; height:100%"></iframe>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you really want to avoid the table elements, you might get some traction out of div tags with `display:table`, `display:table-row`, and `display:table-cell`, but be prepared for even more annoying quirks in certain browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">
<body style="margin:0; >
<p style="margin:10px"> hello </p>
<iframe src="http://www.weather.com" style="width:100%; height:100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Well, this seems to be a tricky but you have to keep `<html>` OR `<body>` tag height 100% to achieve this

Comment: Does not work.. it just sets the height to the height of the whole screen. But since there's the paragraph `<p ..> .. </p>`, the bottom of the iframe falls off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If your `<p>` tag content is fixed then you can try [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/SwGnR/4/) by adjusting the height of `<p>` and `<iframe>` relatively..and you have to keep `<html>` OR `<body>` tag height 100% otherwise it wont work

Comment: In your jsFiddle link, the iframe clearly does not reach the bottom of the page...

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem recently.  I believe you are wanting to expand the height to fit the content that is dynamically loaded.  This works like a dream.  :)

```
<!--This script will auto size the height.  Must set the id for it to work.-->      
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//
 function sizeFrame() {
 var F = document.getElementById("myFrame");
 if(F.contentDocument) {
 F.height = F.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight+30; //FF 3.0.11, Opera 9.63, and Chrome
 } 
 else {
  F.height = F.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+30; //IE6, IE7 and Chrome
 }

 }

 window.onload=sizeFrame; 

//-->
</script>
```

Comment: This is only possible for same-domain iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Iframe which is a child to the body element is of 100% height with it's parent and before you can make `iframe` full page you have to declare the height of the `body` and make it full page too.

Try this. (I thought it would be better if you put your CSS in an external file or just inside the `head`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
body {height:100%;}
iframe {height:100%;width:100%;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0">
<p style="margin:10px"> hello </p>
<iframe src="http://www.weather.com"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XVVV2/)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    html, body 
    { 
        height: 100%;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;    
    } 

    #divHeader
    {
        height:25px;

    }
    #divContent
    {   
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
      margin-top:-25px;
    padding-top:25px;
    overflow:hidden;    
    }
    iframe
    {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="divHeader">
        header
    </div>
    <div id="divContent">
    <iframe src="http://www.weather.com"></iframe>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body 
      { 
        height: 100%;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;    
      } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.weather.com" onload="this.height = document.body.offsetHeight;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

You could check the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j7fpq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can't. I tried this before, but it is an issue with the iframe it will remain this way, until they find a way to expose the height of the inner html document... following the standards. If you remove the DOCTYPE of the inner document, I guess you'll have some access to it. [Make Iframe to fit 100% of container's remaining height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325273/make-iframe-to-fit-100-of-containers-remaining-height)

Answer (score 0):

I have always used height:100vh; to give you 100% of the view port

Comment: It would be wise to remember that there is still a prevalent iOS bug when using `vh` - have a look at http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: oh thanks! I didnt know Ill take a look at it then. It works for me at the moment though