# Check if user scrolls down through the iframe to the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I've got just a basic iframe, ind the middle of my page which looks like this:

```
<iframe class="iframe" src="http://route-to.page"></iframe>
```

When a user srolls down to this iframe, it will get extra css class, which will make the iframe full screen, with the following css style:

```
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Now to the point: When a user scrolls down through this full screen iframe all the way to the bottom, it should remove the full screen css class from the iframe. This way, the user can continue scrolling through the rest of my page.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the opposite of what you're doing to detect the top of the iFrame ?

Comment: Providing your current code for detecting the top of the iframe may help someone give you a better solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iframe reaches bottom of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146793/iframe-reaches-bottom-of-page)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
//do something
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
$("#iframeid").load(function () {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeid").contentWindow;
    $(iframe).scroll(function () {
        if (   $(iframe).scrollTop()==$(iframe).height()-$("#iframeid").height()) {
            alert("Reached bottom!");             
        }
    });
});
})
```