# How to set a max width of published google doc?

Tags: google-docs

Google doc, once published takes the whole screen width. It doesn't look good for reading - long lines are really not user friendly (image below).

Is it possible to limit the content width (eg to max 900px)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manage and limit the content width, you would have to embed the document to a web page as an `iframe`, following [these steps](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965#embed_files). This way:

- The margins you set in the document via `File > Page setup` will be mantained.
- You can set the width and height of the `iframe` with the [corresponding HTML attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Attributes) and with `CSS`:

For example, if you wanted the `iframe` to have certain width, you could do the following:

```html
<iframe width="900" src="published-doc-url">
```

Or, if you want the width to be dynamic, you could, for example, try something on the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23027242).

#### Publish an Apps Script Web App:

An easy way to publish and share this is by deploying an [Apps Script Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web):

You would just have to create an HTML file, add the `iframe` to it, create a script file (`.gs`) that contains this function:

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("your-html-file-name");
}
```

And finally publish the web app, as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app).

#### Reference:

- [Make Google Docs, Sheets, Slides & Forms public > Embed files](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965#embed_files)
- [Apps Script: Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: Thanks for answering. For me this looks like a workaround. I would prefer to directly customize the published web-page, so I don't need to create new apps. https://docs.google.com/document/d/18wxxXYqCFPQYQtBrs6AEO3t07IYNDEwhC8Og9MZh2GY/pub

Comment: @RobertZaremba Of course it is a workaround, but it's the best I can think of. I don't think you can directly customize the published Doc.