# How do I combine a Quarto Website with Quarto Dashboard?

Tags: r, dashboard, quarto

[Quarto](https://quarto.org/) is a very impressive and handy scientific publishing system. You can create really nice websites with it. Now, you can also create [Dashboards](https://quarto.org/docs/dashboards/) rather easily with Quarto.

But is there a way to combine both? So create a website and integrate a dashboard into this website as a subside (but with the same design)?

If so, how do you do it and are there any good practice examples?

Comment: This is a really interesting question. I'm also not sure how to add your dashboards to the blog section of your website. @shafee do you have any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code? I may have an idea for this.

Comment: I do not have a code yet because I wanted to clarify this point before starting programming. Can you please elaborate what your idea is?

Comment: You may want to use the html output of your dashboards and place them in an iframe at a certain place on your website. I’m not sure if this works with server based dashboards.

Comment: I had a somehow similar idea. Create a website and then create a folder with a quarto dashboard in it.

Comment: I will try to make a reproducible example in a couple of hours

Comment: Oh, I am looking forward to the results. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could create dashboards using the `format: dashboard` in a qmd file and use the html output inside an `<iframe>` to have the dashboard displayed on a certain page of your website. Here I'm trying to create a reproducible example. At first I create a dashboard use one of the [examples](https://quarto.org/docs/dashboards/examples/) of the quarto website and call the file `example_dashboard.qmd` which returns a `example_dashboard.html` file. Now I create a website in a project called `example_website`. I add an extra folder called `dashboards` where we place the html files. Now we create a page in our website which will display the dashboards called `dashboards.qmd` like this:

```
---
title: "Dashboards"
---

Here is an example of a dashboard:

<iframe width = "1200" height="700" src = "dashboards/example_dashboard.html"></iframe>
```

Place the name of this file in the `yaml` file and as you can see we use the `iframe` section to show the html file which is our dashboard. Here is an output of the folder structure:

[image]

When we render the website we get the following output:

[image]

As you can see we can combine the dashboard inside a website.

Comment: Pretty cool workaround. But using a iframe also means that you have a fixed width and height of this frame. This could get problematic, when you access the website on a mobile phone or tablet. Or am I wrong?

Comment: That is a good question. I do think it will change on mobile or tablet (I can't reproduce now). An option may be to use 100% width and height like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027068/how-to-set-the-iframe-height-width-to-100). This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-and-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it) and answers are also useful for this.