# fix Iframe height in Percentage to aquire contents full height

Tags: html, css, iframe, resize, frameset-iframe

I have implemented iframe like this

```html
<iframe name="Container" width="100%" height="900px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Here i am fixing the height using pixels which will create problem when i change screen resolution. Since content which will be displayed in iframe vary every time(target used for different html's to display in iframe )Hence i want to fix frames height in Percentage.So that it could display whole content without scroll bar.
Thank you

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325273/make-iframe-to-fit-100-of-containers-remaining-height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<iframe name="Container" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Try this code. You can set height equal to 100%. In order to solve the problem